# Syntax for JSONPath filtering to not return array

Tags: azure, jsonpath

I'm new to JSONPath and want to write a JSONPath-syntax that retrieves the property value only if a certain condition is met. The value I'm after is not part of an array, but I've managed to make filtering work in the following JSONPath tool: https://www.site24x7.com/tools/json-path-evaluator.html

Given the following JSON, I only want to extract the value of `column2.dimValue` if `column2.attributeId` equals B0:

```
{
    "batchId": 279,
    "companyId": "40",
    "period": 202208,
    "taxCode": "1",
    "taxSystem": "",
    "transactionDate": "2022-08-05T00:00:00.000",
    "transactionNumber": 222006089,
    "transactionType": "IF",
    "year": 2022,
    "accountingInformation": {
        "account": "4010",
        "column1": {
            "attributeId": "H9",
            "dimValue": "76"
        },
        "column2": {
            "attributeId": "B0",
            "dimValue": "2170103"
        },
        "column3": {
            "attributeId": "",
            "dimValue": ""
        },
        "column4": {
            "attributeId": "BF",
            "dimValue": "217010330"
        },
        "column5": {
            "attributeId": "10",
            "dimValue": "3101"
        },
        "column6": {
            "attributeId": "06",
            "dimValue": ""
        },
        "column7": {
            "attributeId": "19",
            "dimValue": "K"
        }
    },
    "categories": {
        "cat1": "H9",
        "cat2": "B0",
        "cat3": "",
        "cat4": "BF",
        "cat5": "10",
        "cat6": "06",
        "cat7": "19",
        "dim1": "76",
        "dim2": "2170103",
        "dim3": "",
        "dim4": "217010330",
        "dim5": "3101",
        "dim6": "",
        "dim7": "K"
    },
    "amounts": {
        "amount": 48.24,
        "amount3": 0.0,
        "amount4": 0.0,
        "currencyAmount": 48.24,
        "currencyCode": "NOK",
        "debitCreditFlag": 1
    },
    "invoice": {
        "customerOrSupplierId": "58118",
        "description": "",
        "externalArchiveReference": "",
        "externalReference": "2170103",
        "invoiceNumber": "220238522",
        "ledgerType": "P"
    },
    "additionalInformation": {
        "number": 0,
        "orderLineNumber": 0,
        "orderNumber": 0,
        "sequenceNumber": 1,
        "status": "",
        "value": 0.0,
        "valueDate": "2022-08-05T00:00:00.000"
    },
    "lastUpdated": {
        "updatedAt": "2022-09-05T10:59:11.633",
        "updatedBy": "HELVES"
    }
}
```

I've used this JSONPath-syntax:

```
$['accountingInformation']['column2'][?(@.attributeId=='B0')].dimValue
```

This gives the following result:

```
[
   "2170103"
]
```

I'm using this result in Azure Data Factory mapping, and it seems that it doesn't work as the result is an array.

Can anyone help me with the syntax to it only returns the actual value? Is that even possible?

Comment: How do you map in ADF? Could you share the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I repro'd the same and below is the approach.

- Sample Json file is taken as in below image as a source in lookup activity.
  [image]
- If activity is taken to filter the value of column2 with attributeId='B0'.  Expression is given as below
  `@equals(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].accountingInformation.column2.attributeId ,'B0')`
- In true case of **IF activity**, **Set Variable** is added. New Variable with string type is taken and it is set using below expression.
  `@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].accountingInformation.column2.dimvalue`

[image]

- Then Copy activity is added next to IF activity sequentially. In source dummy dataset is taken.  **+New** is click in additional columns

> Name: col1
> Value: @variables('v2')

[image]

- In Mapping, **Import schemas** is clicked. All other columns except the additional column that is added in source are deleted.

[image]

- Pipeline is debugged and data is copied to sink without error.
  [image]